# Character encoding Ascii and UTF8

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, ascii

I need to add a character to a string as a crc check. The string consists of 125 characters. The 125'th character is the crc character.

I loop over the 124 first characters adding their ascii values together, doing some bit-stuff with the sum and calculating the ascii value for the last character (the 125'th character).

The ascii value may be > 127 and <= 255. I have to get the string-representation for this value (some times called extended ascii character).

I have tried this:

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 155]
```

but printing s1 in the debugger show @"". I would expect s1 to be @"ø".

Something tells me I have to use UTF8 but how would I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `%c` instead?

Comment: is the debugger capable of displaying extended ascii chars?

Comment: Why do you expect 155 to be 'ø'? Which character encoding should that be?

Comment: Hi Martin. According to this http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-u-grave-accent-ascii-code-151.html

Comment: @user1152964: That looks like http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_850 which is used by DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 155];` instead.
The '%c' specifier will give you a 8-Bit character, while '%C' gives you a 16-Bit char.

Comment: Hi. This doesn't work. S1 ends up equaling empty string.

Comment: Thats strange. When i print s1 like so: NSLog(@"%@", s1); I get 'õ' as the output...

Comment: short:
   int s1 = 155;
    NSString *s11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", s1];
    NSString *s111 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)s1];
    NSLog(@"%@", s11);
    NSLog(@"%@", s111);
 gives a question mark upside down character!

Comment: Actually, I think your code is correct, but the console will often print an upside down question mark for "unusual" characters and sometimes it even prints whitespace chars.

Comment: NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)155];
int check = [s1 characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%C", [s1 characterAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"%i", check);

Prints the question mark and '155', so the character might not be displayed correctly in the console, but it is definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along these lines

```
int i = 155;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)];

NSLog(@"val: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                        encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

or NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: Not UTF8. The checksum character won't be valid UTF8.

Comment: And likely not NSASCIIStringEncoding either, which is a strict 7-bit encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The checksum byte means this data isn't really a valid string encoding, and you will likely have other problems if you try to represent it as NSString. You should use NSData instead.

Comment: Hi Greg. Could you please be a little more specific and maybe show an example?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  int checksum = 200;
  NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: &checksum 
                                            length: 1 
                                          encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
  NSString *str1 = @"abc";
  NSString *str = [str1 stringByAppendingString: str2];


checksum    int 200 200
str2    __NSCFString         *  @"È"    0x00000001001105a0
str1    __NSCFConstantString *  @"abc"  0x0000000100002980
str     __NSCFString         *  @"abcÈ" 0x00000001001109f0
```

As mentioned the 'ASCII' encoding is strictly 7 bits.

If you do the same as above but with '155' the character won't show.  But it is there:

```
(lldb) call [str characterAtIndex: 0]
(unsigned short) $0 = 97
(lldb) call [str characterAtIndex: 1]
(unsigned short) $1 = 98
(lldb) call [str characterAtIndex: 2]
(unsigned short) $2 = 99
(lldb) call [str characterAtIndex: 3]
(unsigned short) $3 = 155
```

Comment: Hi. Well it works if checksum equals 200, but not if it equals 155. Can you explain?

Comment: sorry. I didn't see you last comment from the debugger. I just don't understand why I can see the character (200) and not the (155) as they are both greater than 127.

Comment: I don't think you should care.  When you've added a 'checksum' it is no longer a 'string' - it is a custom data structure of your own design.  You choose to use a 'stringy thingy' as your data structure; but it is not a 'string'.